# org.apache.http.header missing therefore loopj doesnt work

Tags: android, loopj

I am trying to use Loopj Async http request library. Header[] component from org.apache.http.Header is used, but it doesn't get recognized because Header doesnt exist inside org.apache.http package.

I've tried adding these items to gradle build but it failed

```
dependencies { compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5' }
android { useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' }
```

Comment: https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/830